# Python and batch file

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file that will open the CMD and start a python script.  I nee Windows 10 to start this at 4 am in the morning and know I have to use the Task Scheduler.

My problems seems to be that when I start the batch file the CMD opens up and goes to the correct directory where the python script is but nothing happens.

I am calling the python script from my batch files as "python file.py".  when I manual type this into the CMD everything works perfectly but I can not figure out how to start the python scrip from within the batch file to be executed within the CMD.

```
starts cmd /k "c: && cd\users\ME\Documents"
python file.py
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the batch file will do things later on to finish certain tasks, so i do need to Batch file.

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete example batch file. State exactly how you're running it in the cases where it fails to work as you expect, and describe exactly what you expect to happen. If the operation of the Python script is relevant, also include a minimal example Python script.

Comment: i have edited my question to include the code for the batch file.  As i have stated above I am trying to run the python script through the Command Line.  The batch file opens the command line to the proper directly but does not execute at all the python script.

Comment: Is `starts` instead of `start` a typo in your question or a typo in the batch file? Also ``C:\`` isn't a valid command. I think you want `start cmd /k cd /d "C:\Users\ME\Documents"`. But is there a reason you need a new console running a new instance of cmd?

Comment: Sorry. typos.  yes it is suppose to be start and i changed changed to "c:\".  CMD is not my issue right now, my issue is why can't i run python from the batch file.

Comment: Typos aside, what's the reason for creating this new console window and shell instance? `python file.py` won't run attached to that console. It'll be attached to the same console as the cmd instance that's executing the batch file and use whatever the current directory is in that instance of cmd.

Comment: Perhaps `cmd /k cd /D "C:\users\ME\Documents" ^&^& python file.py`?

Comment: Check it out, it may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066338/command-prompt-returning-blank-but-python-console-doesnt/42068788#42068788

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run python scripts using batch files I format it like this:

```
    "C:\Users\...\python.exe" "C:\Users...\file.py"
```

The first command is the location of your python executionable, and the second is the location of the script you want to run.

An optional extra is to include

```
    pause
```

at the end of your batch file to ensure the cli remains open.